Why are the images so small in my javax.swing application?
I'm creating a Uno game using java's Swing framework for my GUI elements. I have a JPanel, and I'm drawing a InageIcon on it using Graphics.drawImage() method in a custom paintComponent() method. However, when I run my application, my images are so small that they are barely visible. I've tried everything that I can think of, but nothing is working. I don't want to use Jlabels. My code is at https://github.com/samarth466/accessible_games. The piece of code that I'm trying to debug is in src/uno directory. Any help would be appreciated!

I don't want to use Jlabels - using a JLabel won't change the size of the image. The image is painted at its default resolution. You could scale the image larger, but then you will get pixelation. If you want larger images then you need to create larger images. Also, don't post a link to github. Instead, if you need more help post an [mre] directly with your question.

Just my 2 cents: CSS 3 is much more modern and current, and mastering CSS 3 animations will (probably) help you in a career as a programmer a lot more than mastering Swing

Sorry, but most readers don't want to browse a github repository, and even if they did, github trees can change or disappear, which eventually would render your question useless to future readers.  Include the relevant code (and links to any images you are using) directly in your question.
